# How to create triggers and classes by php into salesforce

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

Can We create triggers and classes by php into salesforce. Can anyone please provide the appropriate guideline for this.Any code base guidance would really helpful?

Comment: Do you want to build a IDE using PHP? There is a good browser based ide available at aside.io.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if there is a way to 'port' PHP into Apex (write PHP to achieve results on the force.com platform without having to learn/write Apex).

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_how_does_apex_work.htm.), triggers and classes are written in Apex and compiled by the Apex Compiler. So the answer to your question is 'no'.

There are however some toolkits where you can use languages like Python and PHP amongst others to do some SOQL queries. Documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP).

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Comment: I know the way this can be achieved by curl and some rest tooling api but didnt know much how to excecute it.

Comment: @Prady No not IDE but can able to upload package to salesforce org by php.